# C++: odd behavior with reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, casting

I have the following snippet

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class foobar
{
    public:
    unsigned int a = 97;
    unsigned int b = 98;
    unsigned int c = 99;
};


class barfoo
{
    public:
    char a:32,b:32,c;

};


int main(){
    foobar * f = new foobar();
    barfoo * b = (reinterpret_cast<barfoo *>(f));
    cout << b->a << "-" << b->b << "-" << b->c;

}
```

Output:

```
a-b-c
```

However, if I specify the width of c in barfoo, it doesn't work (all the values are 0). Observe

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class foobar
{
    public:
    unsigned int a = 97;
    unsigned int b = 98;
    unsigned int c = 99;
};


class barfoo
{
    public:
    char a:32,b:32,c:32;

};


int main(){
    foobar * f = new foobar();
    barfoo * b = (reinterpret_cast<barfoo *>(f));
    cout << b->a << "-" << b->b << "-" << b->c;

}
```

Output:

```
--
```

The chars are all 0

Any idea why this is happening?

Link to ideone [first snippet](http://ideone.com/umvW0J) -- working

Linke to ideone [second snippet](http://ideone.com/jo5hGS) -- not working

Compiler is gcc-5.1
Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure `char a:32` can hold 32 bits? Also I wouldn't expect too much consistency when using UB.

Comment: What you are doing is called Undefined Behavior. Therefore `reinterpret_cast` behavior is correct in this case. It crashing your program will be correct behavior too. Formatting your hard drive is correct behavior. Making demons fly out your nose is correct behavior. Nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, it compiled and the output appears correct. Hence, I'm inclined to say yes. Furthermore, when a char is parsed, it is still only 8 bits, this is just to align the fields.

Comment: You should probably tell what compiler/platform you're using. What happens in cases like this is very much dependent on that (and the explanation too).

Comment: @Kariem Well, appearing to work correctly is also correct. You just don't get any guarantee that it will always work correctly.

Comment: @skyking I'm using the Ideone with gcc-5.1

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I always look forward to explanations of what could occur as part of undefined behavior. But "demons fly out your nose" is one of the more imaginative ones that I've seen.

Comment: @JonathanMee It is an old part of [net folklore](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). [Time travel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) is another possibility BTW.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Snap, how have I not been exposed to this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check if the 2 classes are even same size. Conceivably, padding and alignment may make the positions of bitfields a, b, and c different from positions of normal members a, b and c etc. Why are you using char for 32-bit bitfields? My compiler warns about bitfield exceeding size of type.

Otherwise (if you change char to unsigned int for barfoo class), regardless of any standardese-UB thrown at you, the reinterpret_cast and access has good chance of working. Maybe even more so if you use the well-supported and well-established idiom of type-punning through a union.

Type-punning through a union is a way of telling your compiler 'these 2 pointers of different types may alias, do not make radical optimizations assuming that they may not alias'.

Answer (score 4):

This `reinterpret_cast` does not meet the requirements for defined behavior, so while the assignment of it's result is acceptable any subsequent access of `b` is undefined behavior:

```
barfoo * b = (reinterpret_cast<barfoo *>(f));
```

A [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) must meet one of these conditions, where the `foobar` is the DynamicType and `barfoo` is the AliasedType:

> - AliasedType is (possibly cv-qualified) DynamicType
> - AliasedType and DynamicType are both (possibly multi-level, possibly cv-qualified at each level) pointers to the same type T
> - AliasedType is the (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of DynamicType
> - AliasedType is an aggregate type or a union type which holds one of the aforementioned types as an element or non-static member (including, recursively, elements of subaggregates and non-static data members of the contained unions): this makes it safe to obtain a usable pointer to a struct or union given a pointer to its non-static member or element.
> - AliasedType is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of DynamicType
> - AliasedType is `char` or `unsigned char`: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of unsigned char.

Since the AliasedType does not fall into any of these conditions the accessing of the `reinterpret_cast`'s result is undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't agree. The `reinterpret_cast` itself is not undefined behavior - in fact the page you linked to states that you should be able to `reinterpret_cast` `b` back to get the same pointer as `f`. It only says that dereferencing `b` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @skyking You're 100% correct. The page I linked directly says: "The cast always succeeds, but the resulting pointer or reference may only be used to access the object if one of the following is true." I have edited. Thank you for taking the time to read and comment rather than down-voting and leaving. You are a boon to my answer specifically and http://stackoverflow.com in general!

Comment: @skyking Hmmm... I can see what you're saying. I've edited the first line.